# Need a trigger that will return(rolls up) minimum value from child records to Parent Record

Tags: trigger, roll-up-summary

I have two standard objects

Quote

QuoteLineItem

Each Quote may have one/more QuoteLineItems or maynot have any QuoteLineItems.
Quote and QuoteLineItem are related with Master Detail Relationship. (Ranout of RollUp Summary Fields)
QuoteLineItem has a formula field(percent type) called `Gross_Margin__C`.
Quote has a custom field called `Minimum_Margin__C`.

I need a trigger on Quote(Parent) that will look at all of it's related QuoteLineItems(child records) `Gross_Margin_c` and returns minimum `Gross_Margin__c` on to the Quote record into the field `Minimum_Margin_C`.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You might want to take a look at this Apex Library which makes writing such triggers easy, http://www.tgerm.com/2012/08/creating-easy-rollup-summary-fields-in.html, i have also wrapped this library in a packaged solution which automatically generates the Apex Triggers, http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/07/new-tool-declarative-rollups-for-lookups/

Comment: You can submit a case to Salesforce support asking for an increase in the maximum number of rollup summary fields. You need to explain your business need, and there is a hard max, either 15 or 20 per object; I don't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the roll up summary via lookup fields from Antony Victorio:

http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/

I've used this a number of times when a master-detail relationship with a standard roll up summary hasn't been an option.